# Nodejs jsdom encoding

Tags: node.js, encoding, iconv, jsdom

I am trying to parse a site with the following tag in the header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
```

following word

> Aflenz - Bürgeralm

My Node js Code:

```
//includes

    var jsdom = require("jsdom");
    var fs = require('fs');
    var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
    var Iconv  = require('iconv').Iconv;
    var iconv = new Iconv('iso-8859-1','utf-8');


 //parsing on callback from jsdom
        var name = $(".name_detail").html();
        console.log("db"+name);
        console.log("db"+iconv.convert(name).toString());
```

Output over ssh:

```
dbAflenz - Bï¿½rgeralm
dbAflenz - BÃ¯Â¿Â½rgeralm
```

Thx in advance

Comment: Does your code need to read the `<head>` or can it just hardcode `ISO-8859-1`? And can you show your current code for parsing JSON? The processing needs to happen in that step, not after like you are doing now.

Comment: sry i dont know excatly what you mean. I parse the site with jsdom(request in the background) and I add jquery to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following ([JSDOM allows to make the request in `binary` format](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/commit/de94af13c203d4d3c56cb29de184c685c9db7dc6)):

```
request({uri: url, encoding: 'binary'}, function(err, request, body) {
     ...
     body = new Buffer(body, 'binary')
     iconv = new Iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF8')
     body = iconv.convert(body).toString()
```

This would help solve the case for conversion.